# API Key Invalida OpenWeatherMap

Tags: javascript, html5, json, css3, api

Estoy tratando de hacer una sencilla aplicación web para obtener los datos del clima a través de la API Openweathermap, pero no logro avanzar, a pesar de haber usado 3 keys distintas, siempre obtengo el mismo resultado por consola:

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see <http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401> for more info."}
```

Les dejo el código de JS para que vean si estoy haciendo algo mal, quizás sea algo simple y no esté dándome cuenta:

```
const api = {
    key: 'xxx',
    url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
}

async function search(query) { // obtener informacion de la API
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${api.url}?q=${query}&appid${api.key}&lang=es`); 
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert('Hubo un error');
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo que pongas un símbolo de **=** después de `&appid`, antes de `${api.key}`.  Si lo pongo a mi me devuelve bien los datos.

Comment: gracias masteguru, luego de intentar varias formas de solucionarlo, me di cuenta del error al poner la direcccion directamente en el navegador, ahi cai en la cuenta de la falta del signo igual en la URL, gracias tambien a @Caldo de particulas primigenio por tu aporte!